# fread isnt reading an updated value despite the file has been changed by another program

Tags: c, file, gcc, fwrite, fread

There are two programs that are working with my special file at the same time. They have a common beginning:

```
    #define TASK_POSITION 0x0100

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <inttypes.h>

    int main() {

        FILE * control_file;
        unsigned int task_code;
        fpos_t task_position;

        control_file = fopen("/home/anonymous/.control", "r+");
        fseek(control_file, TASK_POSITION, SEEK_SET);
        fgetpos(control_file, &task_position);
```

But later they have a very different code

- 1st program could change a value at TASK_POSITION offset of this file:

  ```
      /* ... lots of code there ... */

      task_code = 0xFEEDFACE;

      fsetpos(control_file, &task_position);
      fwrite(&task_code, 4, 1, control_file);
        fflush(control_file);
          sleep(1);

      fclose(control_file);
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- 2nd program is repeatedly freading a value at the same offset of this file:

  ```
      for (;;) {
          fsetpos(control_file, &task_position);
          fread(&task_code, 4, 1, control_file);
          if (task_code == 0xFEEDFACE) {
              /* ... Do something awesome! ... */
          }
          else { // remove after debugging
            fprintf(stdout, "not hungry yet :P 0x%08x value has been read... \n"); 
            fflush(stdout);
          }
          sleep(60);
      }

      // just in case
      fclose(control_file);
      return 0; 
  }
  ```

By default, there is 0x12345678 value stored at TASK_POSITION offset.

**Here is a problem:**

after the 1st program has been launched and completed its' work, I could see in a hex editor that a special file has been changed successfully. However: for some unknown to me reason, fread of 2nd program keeps reading the same old value - 0x12345678 !

Although I found a temporary workaround by fclosing/fopening this file during the each iteration of 2nd program's infinite cycle (between the fread checks) it does not look like the best possible solution! Please tell: how to force fread to actually re-read a new value from a file, instead of just returning a previously read value (from its' cache??) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C's standard I/O functions are typically buffered.  To disable buffering, you can do:

```
setvbuf(control_file, NULL, _IONBUF, 0);
```

*immediately* after you open the file, before you perform any I/O on it.

Comment: Your answer is really helpful! Because when I tried googling this problem I didn't find any answers (and thought of cache instead of buffer) Thank you very much! Thanks to you, now I can feed that face in an elegant way ;-)

Comment: What if you simply set the buffer to the size of the previous message that went through it or the size of the next message, whichever is larger? A buffer being available usually speeds up processing, so I'm a bit hesitant with the idea of just getting rid of it, but also am not a fan of hard-coded limits unless they have a good reason.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck I doubt that would help; you could still read a stale cached value.  Buffering *is* useful; it's a fairly rare situation like this where you would want to disable it.  If you have a different case where you want buffering but might read stale data, then perhaps you should ask a separate question for your own situation.

Comment: @jamesdlin That makes sense. What if you disabled it, and then immediately re-enabled it?