# Why rewind() followed by fscanf() do not reflect changes made on disk?

Tags: c, file-io, fopen, rewind

I am repeatedly reading a previously-opened file using `fscanf` and `rewind`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void read_opened_file(FILE *file, int *value)
{
   errno = 0;
   fscanf(file, "%d", value);
   if (errno != 0) perror("fscanf error");
   
   errno = 0;
   rewind(file);
   if (errno != 0) perror("rewind error");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int value = 0;
   FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   
   errno = 0;
   if (setvbuf(file, NULL, _IONBF, 0) != 0) perror("setvbuf error");
   
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
   {
      read_opened_file(file, &value);
      printf("value = %d\n", value); fflush(stdout);
      sleep(1);
   }

   fclose(file);
   return 0;
}
```

However, any changes made to the file on disk behind the scenes by `gedit`, `echo >`, `cp` are not reflected: the function keeps reporting the first (cached?) value read (and `errno` is not set).

- When I `setvbuf(file, NULL, _IONBUF, 0);` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347275/fread-isnt-reading-an-updated-value-despite-the-file-has-been-changed-by-another), changes made by `cp` and `echo >` are reflected, but changes made by `gedit` are still not reflected.
- When I use `fopen` and `fclose` every loop iteration everything is as expected.

How do I fix the above code **without** `fopen` and `fclose` every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The `gedit` program does *not* change the file. That's simply not how it works. So you will not see any change to the file.

The changes `gedit` makes are done by replacing the old file with a new file. You *must* close the old file and open the new file to see the changes that `gedit` made.

Comment: Any idea why the "cached" value keeps showing up if the file is replaced by `gedit`?

Comment: @Sparkler The old file is replaced with the new file in the directory. But if you have the old file open, that has no effect on you. You won't somehow close the old file and open the new file automatically. It is perfectly legal and well-defined to keep a file open after it has been replaced with a different file in one or more directories.

Comment: I think OP's claim that the same happened with `echo >` or `cp` is false, too. These do not create new files but overwrite the existing file.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE At least on my machine, `echo > foo` opens and truncates `foo` rather than replacing it.

Comment: @David: Yes, this is a hard requirement of the shell command language.