# How to constantly read a file in C?

Tags: c, linux

Bear with me, I'm aware this is a simple question, but I feel I may have hit some kind of compiler optimization or other trickery behind the scenes that I can't explain.

Here's my simple, very unoptimized code that looks to read `/sys/class/power_supply/AC/online` to check if my laptop is connected to AC power or not:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE* AC = fopen("/sys/class/power_supply/AC/online", "r");
    int online;

    while (1) {
        fscanf(AC, "%d", &online);
        fseek(AC, 0, SEEK_SET);
        printf("Online: %d\n", online);
    }

    fclose(AC);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm aware the code has no error handling, nor any way to exit the loop, the purpose of it was purely to "test" reading a file constantly. Later I plan to use `inotify` and other things to make it reactive rather than infinitely polling, but thats not the point. The code works, reads the file, but for some reason, will never update that value even after I reposition the file position indicator. The **ONLY** time it changes is if I `^C` the application and restart it, but of course this would work, since it re-opens the file.

I will admit I'm new-ish to C, but not new to programming and from what I can see and read online, this *should* work, at least for the purpose of what I'm trying to test, but no matter what I do, I can't seem to make it work.

Some of the things I've tried:

- Using `rewind()` instead of `fseek()`
- Moving `fseek()` before `fscanf()`, to **absolutely** ensure I read from the beginning of the file
- Using `malloc()` to allocate `online` manually to the heap, then writing data into the pointer.
- Adding a delay via `sleep()` from `unistd.h`

I'm almost convinced I'm either overlooking a very basic fact about C, or there may be some PC optimizations at play that are preventing me from reading this file constantly in the loop. I'd appreciate an external point of view because at this point I feel very stumped.

Just for clarity, I do NOT compile with any optimizations (using `gcc -o main src/main.c && ./main`), so I don't think it's any compiler optimizations.

EDIT: At the suggestion of @JonathanLeffler, I added `clearerr`, but it doesn't seem to be accomplishing anything.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE* AC = fopen("/sys/class/power_supply/AC/online", "r");
    int online;

    while (1) {
        fscanf(AC, "%d", &online);
        clearerr(AC);
        fseek(AC, 0, SEEK_SET);

        printf("Online: %d\n", online);
    }

    fclose(AC);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT 2: Updated with some more "test" code to understand the file state, only further confused.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE* AC = fopen("/sys/class/power_supply/AC/online", "r");
    int online;

    while (1) {
        fseek(AC, 0, SEEK_SET);
        fscanf(AC, "%d", &online);

        // this never runs
        if (feof(AC) != 0) {
            printf("Hit EOF!\n");
            return 1;
        }

        // this never runs
        if (ferror(AC) != 0) {
            printf("Clearing err!\n");
            clearerr(AC);
        }

        printf("Online: %d\n", online);
    }

    fclose(AC);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you have to reopen the file.

Comment: Does the timestamp of the file change when the power status changes?  If yes, you only need to open / read / close the file when the timestamp changes.  Also, when you open it it should be read only and shared mode so the OS?  driver? whatever can update the file while you have it  open.

Comment: @ulix I figured that was probably my only choice, though I heavily wanted to avoid it because I was worried about the overhead cost of re-opening a file over and over.

Comment: I assume you checked your fseek was returning 0?  Regardless, those files in /sys likely do not behave as normal files do.  If you're that concerned about the code working you should try and point it to a file you can modify and see how it behaves.

Comment: @DaveS good point, timestamps don't seem to be changing, and I'm viewing with `ls -lah`, I believe sysfs doesn't change timestamps

Comment: @possum yes I initially checked then removed the code, but `fseek` was indeed returning 0. You've got a good point about the files in `/sys` not behaving the same, it could be a possible `sysfs` quirk. I'll run a test on my own controlled file instead.

Comment: @possum Tested with my own file, it did not update the value in the program, so this is not a `sysfs` quirk.

Comment: Once the file stream hits EOF, you have to call `clearerr()` to make it ready to try again.  Consider pausing on reaching EOF before trying again — but whether that's what you need will depend on what you're really up to.  If you only want to read the data once, you won't be resetting to offset 0 on EOF; you'll stay where you are, waiting for more input.

Comment: I do not think that it is not portable to read those files directly. For this, I would use udev using libudev which provides a stable nad portable  API for it.

Comment: @0___________ You're definitely right its not portable, but for my test-case I wasn't trying to make a portable solution, but just one that could work on my machine.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler didn't know about this, I'll try this suggestion and let you know if it works out.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler please see my updated question, I've added in `clearerr` right after the `fscanf` since it should hit EOF after reading the one character. This does not change the output, which is still stuck at whatever it was when the program first launched

Comment: Actually scratch that, I'm running extra tests via `feof` and `ferror` and it seems that the file does NOT hit `EOF` after `fscanf`, because both `feof and ferror` return 0, which according to `man 3 feof` means they are NOT set. This implies `clearerr` wouldn't be accomplishing anything since there is no error to clear.

Comment: Little update, I changed my code to force fscanf to read until EOF, and suddenly it works. I'm completely bewildered but it does indeed work. `ftell()` return 2 when the file is `EOF`, and my previous example would only ever read to `ftell() == 1`. I don't know why reading TILL EOF then `clearerr` resolves my issue, but it does.

Comment: Check this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39348098/92200

There's a typo in their answer, and it should use "_IONBF".

This made your original example work for me, testing on an ordinary (not /sys) file.

Comment: @Frontear, Skipping error handling is not a wise choice.  Especially, if `fscanf(AC, "%d", &online)` does not return 1, then there are issues.

Comment: @Neil your solution also works. I'm beginning to see it has something to do with file buffering, since possum's answer also works, because it flushes the buffers.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I agree, in this case I chose only to skip because I could guarantee there were no errors (I ran the code through once with error handling, then when none fired I removed them to simplify what I needed to post online)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On regular files you should ensure you `fflush` the buffers.

```
 while (1) {
        fscanf(AC, "%d", &online);
        fseek(AC, 0, SEEK_SET);

        printf("Online: %d\n", online);
        fflush(AC);
    }
```

Comment: Fascinatingly, this fixes the issue. Is there a possibility you could add a more detailed explanation behind the reasoning _why_ we need to flush the buffers. What's happening internally, or behind the scenes for this to be needed. If you could add this I'd be more than happy to accept this as the answer, because I like this solution infinitely more.

Comment: When you read from a file, the contents of the file will be buffered in the STDIO buffer,  When doing a fseek to a point that's already in the buffer, it just moves the buffer pointer and doesn't actually read any new data.  `fflush` ensures the buffered data is discarded, so and subsequent `fscanf` or other read operation will re-read from the underlying file.

Comment: From the documentation:  "The function fflush() synchronizes the state of the given stream in light of buffered I/O.  For output or update  streams it writes all buffered data via the stream's underlying write function."  There's clearly data stuck in a buffer from whatever is controlling your file. That just makes it available.  It's a pretty common thing to do when working with IO streams.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Your comment makes a lot of sense, thank you, this is very valuable knowledge.