# Impossibility to clear the buffer

Tags: c, buffer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

void perimeter(double, double, double, double *, double *);
double square(double, double, double, double);
void heights(double, double, double, double *, double *, double *, double);
void medians(double, double, double, double *, double *, double *);
void bisectors(double, double, double, double *, double *, double *, double);

int main()
{
    char buffer[32];
    double first_side = 0;
    double second_side = 0;
    double third_side = 0;
    
    double per1;
    double per2;
    
    double height_to_firstside;
    double height_to_secondside;
    double height_to_thirdside;
    
    double median_to_firstside;
    double median_to_secondside;
    double median_to_thirdside;
    
    double bisector_to_firstside;
    double bisector_to_secondside;
    double bisector_to_thirdside;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter a number for side %d: ", i + 1);
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin); // Зчитуємо рядок
        
        //Validation
        if (strspn(buffer, "0123456789.") != strlen(buffer) - 1) 
        {
            printf("Invalid input. Please enter other nums.\n");
            return 0;
        }
        
        int dot_count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(buffer); j++)
        {
            if (buffer[0] == '0' && buffer[1] != '.')
            {
                printf("Invalid input. Please enter other nums.\n");
                return 0;
            }
            
            if (buffer[j] == '.')
            {
                dot_count++;
            }
            if (dot_count >= 2)
            {
                printf("Invalid input. Please enter other nums.\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }
        
        double input;
        sscanf(buffer, "%lf", &input);

        if (i == 0) // Зберігаємо значення в відповідній змінній
        {
            first_side = input;
        }
        else if (i == 1)
        {
            second_side = input;
        }
        else if (i == 2)
        {
            third_side = input;
        }
        /*int c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));*/
    }

    if ((first_side + second_side) < third_side || (second_side + third_side) < first_side || (first_side + third_side) < second_side)
    {
        printf("Unreal triangle, enter other nums\n");
        return 0;
    }

    perimeter(first_side, second_side, third_side, &per1, &per2);
    double area = square(first_side, second_side, third_side, per2);
    heights(first_side, second_side, third_side, &height_to_firstside, &height_to_secondside, &height_to_thirdside, per2);
    medians(first_side, second_side, third_side, &median_to_firstside, &median_to_secondside, &median_to_thirdside);
    bisectors(first_side, second_side, third_side, &bisector_to_firstside, &bisector_to_secondside, &bisector_to_thirdside, per2);

    //results
    printf("Perimeter: %lf\n", per1);
    printf("Semi-perimeter: %lf\n", per2);
    
    printf("Square: %lf\n", area);
    
    printf("Height for the first side: %lf\n", height_to_firstside);
    printf("Height for the second side: %lf\n", height_to_secondside);
    printf("Height for the third side: %lf\n", height_to_thirdside);
    
    printf("Median for the first side: %lf\n", median_to_firstside);
    printf("Median for the second side: %lf\n", median_to_secondside);
    printf("Median for the third side: %lf\n", median_to_thirdside);
    
    printf("Bisector for the first side: %lf\n", bisector_to_firstside);
    printf("Bisector for the second side: %lf\n", bisector_to_secondside);
    printf("Bisector for the third side: %lf\n", bisector_to_thirdside);

    return 0;
}

void perimeter(double first, double second, double third, double *pPer1, double *pPer2)
{
    *pPer1 = first + second + third;
    *pPer2 = *pPer1 / 2;
}

double square(double first, double second, double third, double semi_perimeter)
{
    double square_size;
    square_size = sqrt(semi_perimeter * (semi_perimeter - first) * (semi_perimeter - second) * (semi_perimeter - third));

    return square_size;
}

void heights(double first, double second, double third, double *pHeight_firstside, double *pHeight_secondside, double *pHeight_thirdside, double semi_perimeter)
{
    *pHeight_firstside = 2 * (sqrt(semi_perimeter * (semi_perimeter - first) * (semi_perimeter - second) * (semi_perimeter - third))) / first;
    *pHeight_secondside = 2 * (sqrt(semi_perimeter * (semi_perimeter - first) * (semi_perimeter - second) * (semi_perimeter - third))) / second;
    *pHeight_thirdside = 2 * (sqrt(semi_perimeter * (semi_perimeter - first) * (semi_perimeter - second) * (semi_perimeter - third))) / third;
}

void medians(double first, double second, double third, double *pMedian_firstside, double *pMedian_secondside, double *pMedian_thirdside)
{
    *pMedian_firstside = 0.5 * (sqrt((2 * second * second) + (2 * third * third) - (first * first)));
    *pMedian_secondside = 0.5 * (sqrt((2 * first * first) + (2 * third * third) - (second * second)));
    *pMedian_thirdside = 0.5 * (sqrt((2 * first * first) + (2 * second * second) - (third * third)));
}

void bisectors(double first, double second, double third, double *pBisector_firstside, double *pBisector_secondside, double *pBisector_thirdside, double semi_perimeter)
{
    *pBisector_firstside = (2 / (second + third)) * (sqrt((second * third * semi_perimeter) * (semi_perimeter - first)));
    *pBisector_secondside = (2 / (first + third)) * (sqrt((first * third * semi_perimeter) * (semi_perimeter - second)));
    *pBisector_thirdside = (2 / (first + second)) * (sqrt((first * second * semi_perimeter) * (semi_perimeter - third)));
}
```

This is my code and as you can see I'm using a character array to get the values from the user, then validate it and finally convert it to a double, but it's all done in a loop, so I'm running into a problem that I can't clear the buffer, and when the user enters the first value, however, omits the next two, then the first value is also assigned to the second and third.

I tried to use `fflush(stdin)`, but it did not work, also I tried this:

```
 int c;
 while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
```

but it did not work either, so I do not even know what I should try now.

Comment: `but it did not worked too` ??? What did not work? Elaborate

Comment: Please show an example of input along with the expected and the actual output as properly formatted text (no picture). Read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]

Comment: BTW: I tested your code, and it works as expected...

Comment: There's no need to do this if you use `fgets()` to read the input, since it reads until newline. You only need to do this if you use `scanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

You sure can clear the input buffer. Or just consume the data, as expected.

`fflush` is not defined for input. At least not for terminal input. From Linux `man` pages:

> *For input streams associated with seekable files (e.g., disk
> files, but not pipes or terminals), fflush() discards any
> buffered data that has been fetched from the underlying file, but
> has not been consumed by the application.*

It is defined for output only and there do not means to `discard` anything. Example: You can have a driver for `stdout` waiting for a `\n` to print the line on a `tty`, but then the program ends. The bytes there are in the buffer are printed anyway: the `OS` flushes the output buffers at the end. If in the code there is a need to immediately really prints the data, then there is `fflush` for it.

Some `C` compilers accepts `fflush` on input streams as extension and, AFAIK, is used by students only.

Under `Windows` for console input you can call

```
BOOL WINAPI FlushConsoleInputBuffer(
  _In_ HANDLE hConsoleInput
);
```

as described in the documentation. On Linux I think you can search for `ioctl` calls or `termios` to do the same.

#### just consume all input data

If you consume all data the input buffer is not a concern of your code.

**I will show you an example, rearranging your code.**

#### use encapsulation

Write your code around your data. Use encapsulation wherever you see a chance. This is not just an **OOP** fancy word. It is a powerful thing.

From your code:

- your data is a triangle
- the user inputs the side's measures
- your code computes some values, after determining that the entered measures are feasible for a triangle
- the values are displayed
- the program ends.

The values computed in your program only makes sense if you have an input triangle. And if the side's measures changes all values are invalidated.

So...

Consider this thing:

```
typedef struct
{
    double   s1;
    double   s2;
    double   s3;
    Measures msrs;
} Triangle;
```

This is your data. As for `msrs`, from your code

```
typedef struct
{
    double perimeter;
    double semi_perimeter;
    double area;
    double height_to_firstside;
    double height_to_secondside;
    double height_to_thirdside;
    double median_to_firstside;
    double median_to_secondside;
    double median_to_thirdside;
    double bisector_to_firstside;
    double bisector_to_secondside;
    double bisector_to_thirdside;
} Measures;
```

Using the values **INSIDE** of `Triangle` makes easy to enforce the dependencies. And also makes it possible to treat an arbitrary number or triangles in your code...

#### how to create a `Triangle`

```
Triangle* so_create()
{
    Triangle* tri = malloc(sizeof(Triangle));
    if (tri == NULL) return NULL;
    printf(
        "    Triangle:\n\tPlease enter values for the 3 "
        "sides: ");
    int res =
        scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &tri->s1, &tri->s2, &tri->s3);
    if (res != 3)
    {
        free(tri);
        return NULL;
    }
    if (not so_is_triangle(tri))
    {
        free(tri);
        return NULL;
    }
    tri->msrs = so_get_measures(tri);
    return tri;
}
```

This is the starting code in `main` in your program. But here

- a single call to `scanf` reads the 3 measures
- in common `C` style, `so_is_triangle()` returns `1` if the measures are ok for a triangle
- it the measures check, a call to `so_get_measures()` computes all triangle's parameteres

Consider these functions:

```
    Triangle* so_create();
    Triangle* so_destroy(Triangle*);
    int       so_is_triangle(Triangle*);
    Measures  so_get_measures(Triangle*);
    int       so_show_triangle(Triangle*, const char*);
```

with be obvious meaning.

#### `main` for a simple test

```
int main(void)
{
    Triangle* one = so_create();
    if (one == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "    Invalid data entered. Please try again\n");
        return -1;
    };
    so_show_triangle(one, "\n\n[First triangle]");
    so_destroy(one);
    return 0;
}
```

It is easier to read this way.

#### output of a test

```
    Triangle:
        Please enter values for the 3 sides: 3 4 5


[First triangle]    Sides: [    3.0000,     4.0000,     5.0000]

    Perimeter:         12.0000
    Semi-perimeter:     6.0000
    Square:             6.0000

    Height for the first side:        4.0000
    Height for the second side:       3.0000
    Height for the third side:        2.4244

    Median for the first side:        4.2720
    Median for the second side:       3.6056
    Median for the third side:        2.5000

    Bisector for the first side:      4.2164
    Bisector for the second side:     3.3541
    Bisector for the third side:      2.4244
```

#### about `so_show_triangle`

Note that 12 printfs of one variable are hundreds of times slower than a single printf of 12 variables. And are harder to correct or align...

Compare:

```
    // results
    printf("Perimeter: %lf\n", per1);
    printf("Semi-perimeter: %lf\n", per2);

    printf("Square: %lf\n", area);

    printf(
        "Height for the first side: %lf\n",
        height_to_firstside);
    printf(
        "Height for the second side: %lf\n",
        height_to_secondside);
    printf(
        "Height for the third side: %lf\n",
        height_to_thirdside);

    printf(
        "Median for the first side: %lf\n",
        median_to_firstside);
    printf(
        "Median for the second side: %lf\n",
        median_to_secondside);
    printf(
        "Median for the third side: %lf\n",
        median_to_thirdside);

    printf(
        "Bisector for the first side: %lf\n",
        bisector_to_firstside);
    printf(
        "Bisector for the second side: %lf\n",
        bisector_to_secondside);
    printf(
        "Bisector for the third side: %lf\n",
        bisector_to_thirdside);
```

with

```
    printf(
        "\
    Sides: [%10.4f, %10.4f, %10.4f]\n\
\n\
    Perimeter:      %10.4f\n\
    Semi-perimeter: %10.4f\n\
    Square:         %10.4f\n\
\n\
    Height for the first side:    %10.4f\n\
    Height for the second side:   %10.4f\n\
    Height for the third side:    %10.4f\n\
\n\
    Median for the first side:    %10.4f\n\
    Median for the second side:   %10.4f\n\
    Median for the third side:    %10.4f\n\
\n\
    Bisector for the first side:  %10.4f\n\
    Bisector for the second side: %10.4f\n\
    Bisector for the third side:  %10.4f\n",
        tri->s1, tri->s2, tri->s3,
        tri->msrs.perimeter, tri->msrs.semi_perimeter,
        tri->msrs.area, tri->msrs.height_to_firstside,
        tri->msrs.height_to_secondside,
        tri->msrs.bisector_to_thirdside,
        tri->msrs.median_to_firstside,
        tri->msrs.median_to_secondside,
        tri->msrs.median_to_thirdside,
        tri->msrs.bisector_to_firstside,
        tri->msrs.bisector_to_secondside,
        tri->msrs.bisector_to_thirdside);
```

used in the example.

### Complete `C` code for the example

```
#include <iso646.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    double perimeter;
    double semi_perimeter;
    double area;
    double height_to_firstside;
    double height_to_secondside;
    double height_to_thirdside;
    double median_to_firstside;
    double median_to_secondside;
    double median_to_thirdside;
    double bisector_to_firstside;
    double bisector_to_secondside;
    double bisector_to_thirdside;
} Measures;

typedef struct
{
    double   s1;
    double   s2;
    double   s3;
    Measures msrs;
} Triangle;

Triangle* so_create();
Triangle* so_destroy(Triangle*);
int       so_is_triangle(Triangle*);
Measures  so_get_measures(Triangle*);
int       so_show_triangle(Triangle*, const char*);

int main(void)
{
    Triangle* one = so_create();
    if (one == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "    Invalid data entered. Please try again\n");
        return -1;
    };
    so_show_triangle(one, "\n\n[First triangle]");
    so_destroy(one);
    return 0;
}

Triangle* so_create()
{
    Triangle* tri = malloc(sizeof(Triangle));
    if (tri == NULL) return NULL;
    printf(
        "    Triangle:\n\tPlease enter values for the 3 "
        "sides: ");
    int res =
        scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &tri->s1, &tri->s2, &tri->s3);
    if (res != 3)
    {
        free(tri);
        return NULL;
    }
    if (not so_is_triangle(tri))
    {
        free(tri);
        return NULL;
    }
    tri->msrs = so_get_measures(tri);
    return tri;
}

Triangle* so_destroy(Triangle* tri)
{
    if (tri == NULL) return NULL;
    free(tri);
    return NULL;
}

int so_is_triangle(Triangle* tri)
{
    if (tri == NULL) return 0;
    if ((tri->s1 + tri->s2) < tri->s3 ||
        (tri->s2 + tri->s3) < tri->s1 ||
        (tri->s1 + tri->s3) < tri->s2)
        return 0;
    return 1;  // ok it is a triangle
}

Measures so_get_measures(Triangle* tri)
{
    Measures m = {0};
    if (tri == NULL) return m;
    // perimeter
    m.perimeter      = tri->s1 + tri->s2 + tri->s3;
    m.semi_perimeter = m.perimeter / 2;
    // area
    m.area = sqrt(
        m.semi_perimeter * (m.semi_perimeter - tri->s1) *
        (m.semi_perimeter - tri->s2) *
        (m.semi_perimeter - tri->s3));
    // heights
    m.height_to_firstside =
        2 *
        (sqrt(
            m.semi_perimeter *
            (m.semi_perimeter - tri->s1) *
            (m.semi_perimeter - tri->s2) *
            (m.semi_perimeter - tri->s3))) /
        tri->s1;
    m.height_to_secondside =
        2 *
        (sqrt(
            m.semi_perimeter *
            (m.semi_perimeter - tri->s1) *
            (m.semi_perimeter - tri->s2) *
            (m.semi_perimeter - tri->s3))) /
        tri->s2;
    m.height_to_thirdside =
        2 *
        (sqrt(
            m.semi_perimeter *
            (m.semi_perimeter - tri->s1) *
            (m.semi_perimeter - tri->s2) *
            (m.semi_perimeter - tri->s3))) /
        tri->s3;
    // medians
    m.median_to_firstside =
        0.5 *
        (sqrt(
            (2 * tri->s2 * tri->s2) +
            (2 * tri->s3 * tri->s3) - (tri->s1 * tri->s1)));
    m.median_to_secondside =
        0.5 *
        (sqrt(
            (2 * tri->s1 * tri->s1) +
            (2 * tri->s3 * tri->s3) - (tri->s2 * tri->s2)));
    m.median_to_thirdside =
        0.5 *
        (sqrt(
            (2 * tri->s1 * tri->s1) +
            (2 * tri->s2 * tri->s2) - (tri->s3 * tri->s3)));
    // bisectors
    m.bisector_to_firstside =
        (2 / (tri->s2 + tri->s3)) *
        (sqrt(
            (tri->s2 * tri->s3 * m.semi_perimeter) *
            (m.semi_perimeter - tri->s1)));
    m.bisector_to_secondside =
        (2 / (tri->s1 + tri->s3)) *
        (sqrt(
            (tri->s1 * tri->s3 * m.semi_perimeter) *
            (m.semi_perimeter - tri->s2)));
    m.bisector_to_thirdside =
        (2 / (tri->s1 + tri->s2)) *
        (sqrt(
            (tri->s1 * tri->s2 * m.semi_perimeter) *
            (m.semi_perimeter - tri->s3)));
    return m;
}

int so_show_triangle(Triangle* tri, const char* msg)
{
    if (tri == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    //
    printf(
        "\
    Sides: [%10.4f, %10.4f, %10.4f]\n\
\n\
    Perimeter:      %10.4f\n\
    Semi-perimeter: %10.4f\n\
    Square:         %10.4f\n\
\n\
    Height for the first side:    %10.4f\n\
    Height for the second side:   %10.4f\n\
    Height for the third side:    %10.4f\n\
\n\
    Median for the first side:    %10.4f\n\
    Median for the second side:   %10.4f\n\
    Median for the third side:    %10.4f\n\
\n\
    Bisector for the first side:  %10.4f\n\
    Bisector for the second side: %10.4f\n\
    Bisector for the third side:  %10.4f\n",
        tri->s1, tri->s2, tri->s3,
        tri->msrs.perimeter, tri->msrs.semi_perimeter,
        tri->msrs.area, tri->msrs.height_to_firstside,
        tri->msrs.height_to_secondside,
        tri->msrs.bisector_to_thirdside,
        tri->msrs.median_to_firstside,
        tri->msrs.median_to_secondside,
        tri->msrs.median_to_thirdside,
        tri->msrs.bisector_to_firstside,
        tri->msrs.bisector_to_secondside,
        tri->msrs.bisector_to_thirdside);

    return 0;
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77216624/impossibility-to-clear-the-buffer
```

Comment: "_fflush on input streams ... is used by students only._" Really?? Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77205233/17592432

Comment: Coffee break. Time to look at your code... and it's not good... `so_get_measures()` returns a struct of 12 `doubles` (96 bytes) on the stack when it could be populating the values directly into the received `Triangle* tri` structure... While not wrong, it's certainly over done...

Comment: @Fe2O3 In your next coffee break maybe you could read more of the SO thread you cited. It is not even related to this. The question there is about special files on `/sys`. Also, if you have Linux you can try a `man 7` on `fflush` to read _"For input streams associated with seekable files (e.g., disk  files, but not pipes or terminals), fflush() discards any buffered data..."_

Comment: @Fe2O3 as for the return by value, my code my decision. I wanted to keep the pointers and references to a minimum. I am sorry to waste almost 100 bytes.

Comment: Just posted that link because you stated "_used by students only_" Not the case... If you're going to rewrite the OP's code, I ask, politely, why you didn't collapse the _trios_ of doubles down into their own arrays (to use indexing instead of verbose explicit names of each variable.) Just curious...

Comment: How about `Measures *m = &tri->msrs;`? Then `m.perimiter = ...` becomes `m->perimeter = ...`. Not onerous, and doesn't involve returning a struct from a function. Just a thought. (Yeah, it'd require using `tri = calloc()` instead of `tri = malloc()`, too...)

Comment: @Fe2O3 this is going nowhere. I will try to explain to you in other words: `fflush` on input is defined _For input streams associated with seekable files (e.g., disk files, but not pipes or terminals)_  For `stdio` we only see it in student's code and because Microsoft accepts it as an extension. As for the standard it is **UB**

Comment: @Fe2O3 In case I need to change the example I will look at all your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: John: "Hello? Helpdesk? Yeah... I'm running your program, entering 3 values as requested, and it keeps terminating. What's wrong with it?" Helpdesk: "You're sure you are entering 3 numbers?" John: "Damn sure!" Helpdesk: "Would you like to book an appt with a consultant to visit your premises?" John: "No, I'll just return this for a refund and buy from your competitor from now on! Good-bye!!" ... What was John's problem? Entering "123.456,147.258,159.236"... Maybe John grew bored retyping values, then angry because the program didn't provide feedback as soon as the first number was entered. :)

Answer (score 0):

While you've made a valiant attempt to validate the user's input, it's hard to read and it seems to be giving you problems. That can happen when more than 50 lines of code is involved.

Below is shown an example using `strtod()` to convert the ASCII number into a `double`. This library function sets the pointer passed as the 2nd argument to point *beyond* a successfully converted floating point value. This code **requires** the user to enter a valid, positive floating point number, perhaps with leading whitespace, and nothing more. Perhaps you will use this and extend it to serve your needs:

```
void get_3posdbls( double *s1, double *s2, double *s3 ) {
    for( int i = 1; i <= 3; ) {
        double *dp = (i == 1) ? s1 : (i == 2) ? s2 : s3;

        char buffer[32];
        printf( "Enter a number for side %d: ", i );
        if( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin ) == 0 )
            return;

        char *next;
        *dp = strtod( buffer, &next );

        if( *dp <= 0.0 || next == buffer || *next != '\n' )
            printf( "Invalid input. Please enter number only\n" );
        else
            i++;
    }
}

int main( void ) {
    for( ;; ) {
        double side1 = 0;
        double side2 = 0;
        double side3 = 0;

        get_3posdbls( &side1, &side2, &side3 );
        printf( "%5.2lf %5.2lf %5.2lf\n\n", side1, side2, side3 );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
Enter a number for side 1: 12.3
Enter a number for side 2: 45.6
Enter a number for side 3: 78.9
12.30 45.60 78.90

Enter a number for side 1: foobar
Invalid input. Please enter number only
Enter a number for side 1: -56.3 // negative values are rejected
Invalid input. Please enter number only
Enter a number for side 1: 35   // typed extra spaces after "35"
Invalid input. Please enter number only
Enter a number for side 1: 35
Enter a number for side 2: 36
Enter a number for side 3: 37
35.00 36.00 37.00

Enter a number for side 1:
```

**EDIT:**
I wrote *valiant attempt* sincerely. However, by attempting to *filter out* bad strings, the code would reject "3.14153e5" (314153.000) because you were probably not aware this is a valid expression of a floating point number. It's often better to spend time learning about Standard Library functions and experimenting with their use.

One further comment on a difference between your code and what's shown here. Notice the code in this function only defines variables at the point at which the variable is used. This practice reduces the need to scroll up & down between declaration and first use.

---

**EDIT** (not part of the OP's question.)
The calculation functions are good, isolating the different derived results, but they are rather verbose and, therefore, difficult to *scan* as being correct and complete.

Here are two versions of the same function:

```
// Version 1
void heights(double first, double second, double third, double *pHeight_firstside, double *pHeight_secondside, double *pHeight_thirdside, double semi_perimeter)
{
    *pHeight_firstside = 2 * (sqrt(semi_perimeter * (semi_perimeter - first) * (semi_perimeter - second) * (semi_perimeter - third))) / first;
    *pHeight_secondside = 2 * (sqrt(semi_perimeter * (semi_perimeter - first) * (semi_perimeter - second) * (semi_perimeter - third))) / second;
    *pHeight_thirdside = 2 * (sqrt(semi_perimeter * (semi_perimeter - first) * (semi_perimeter - second) * (semi_perimeter - third))) / third;
}

// Version 2
void heights(double s1, double s2, double s3, double *pH_s1, double *pH_s2, double *pH_s3, double sp)
{
    double numerator = 2 * sqrt(sp * (sp - s1) * (sp - s2) * (sp - s3));

    *pH_s1 = numerator / s1;
    *pH_s2 = numerator / s2;
    *pH_s3 = numerator / s3;
}
```

Less (correct) code is better code.

Comment: Note that `strtod()` will accept a variety of syntaxes the OP seems to want to reject: leading whitespace, leading sign, exponent notation, infinities, nan values, hexadecimal syntax...

Comment: @chqrlie While that's true, the OP's code is performing these tests by picking apart the input string. Harmless whitespace and a sign character may not have been considered by the OP when rejecting everything but digits and periods. Then there's repeated tests that the value doesn't begin "0.????" and how many periods has the user tried to type. Should the OP wish to pre-screen, there's nothing preventing that. With `*dp <= 0.0`, my hope was to demonstrate rejecting negative values. Looking closer, perhaps that should be `*dp <= 1.0`. This is just an offering. :-)

Comment: We are on the same page, `strtod` is definitely better than the OPs *valiant* yet cumbersome and inconsistent screening process (eg: why reject `+1.0` and `0`?) Your offering is much more effective and teaches to use standard APIs.  Rejecting non finite values is easy using `isfinite(*dp)` but you might document that too.  Also `get_3posdbls()` should return a success indicator.

Comment: @chqrlie I'd be more than happy to embellish this with more bells & whistles, but, imho, it's not a high value question for the archives... (However... Rejecting `0.0` is probably a good idea for this program wanting to calc triangle characteristics :-) Look at the "formula" used in `heights()`... :-)

Comment: Good thing it is a triangle and not an hexagon. Why not to do the simple as I showed you and show a single prompt and use a single call to `scanf` to get the measures and convert to `double`? When someone runs this code it is already known that will be a triangle involved. It is in general boring to wait for the prompts and press ENTER 3 times. Not to mention that if the user can enter the measures at once it is possible to correct a mistake on the 1st or 2nd or 3rd :)

Comment: And you say my program is _no good_  :)

Comment: @arfneto The answer you posted was an unrecognisable rewrite of the OP's code that had memory leaks. You include `<iso646.h>` with no explanation, and then only for a single token. Instead of demonstrating how the calculations could be expressed more simply, you've increased the complexity by pooling the OP's separate functions into a single function. And, when asked to explain something, you reply "my code my way". SO answers are to address the OP's concerns, not to totally revamp their code as if in some competition. QED...

Comment: @arfneto Just looked at your `scanf()` to take in 3 values at once... The user may not notice a typing mistake before pressing ENTER, and your version terminates the program with malice. It does not validate input allowing the user to re-enter a **single** mis-keyed measurement. Instead, your version requires the user to restart the program and re-enter **all three** values. Trivial for small values, but onerous (and "boring") when taking in values such as "458612.34589"... In other words, "_not good_".

Comment: @Fe2O3 it seems you do not have experience with user interface. As I told you, when a user knows that 3 values are needed is really annoying to see prompt after prompt --- since it probably know the measures of the 3 sides --- and there is also the simple matter that there is no opportunity to retype all values, only the last. Good there not 6 or 8 sides :D Even you can get bored by having to type 3 values and press ENTER 3 times just to do the obvious in your own code. Or not.

Comment: @arfneto "_it seems you do not have experience..._" ... Ah, the ad hominin defense... You know nothing about my experience.

Comment: @arfneto You're failing to see that `scanf()` you are promoting will be equally satisfied when John enters "3 4 5 ENTER" as with "3 ENTER 4 ENTER 5 ENTER"... Let's end this here, please... John won't be fussed, one way or the other...

Comment: Failing? There is no point in it. What is up if the user types one hundred ENTER? Makes not different what I explained you. One prompt for each value is frustrating, annoying and gives far less chance of correcting values.  I am not promoting anything. `scanf` was not even written for this, taking keyboard input. These **scan**ners were written for consume  big files of tabular data.

Comment: @arfneto "_scanf was not even written for this, taking keyboard input_" Then, why does your answer to this question (completely revising the OP's code) continue to use `scanf()` without comment? ... Never mind... You've already written, "my code my decision"...